# How can i specify the relative file of dtsconfig file for SSIS in SQL JOBS

Tags: sql, ssis, jobs

I am working with ssis package. and i developed some packages with the configuration file. In the configuration file i given the all relative paths of the connections like FlatFileConnection, OLEDB Connection etc. it is running fine with dtexec command with /config configuration file path.

But now i need to create a sql job to run this ssis package automatically every day. In this case i want to give the relative path of the config file(I dont want to hard code to the path of configuration file. it should take from the same path of the .dtsx file path) . how can i do this?

Thanks in advance.
Eshwer

Answer (score 1):

You can’t!

You must have the path for the config file on your job step. 
If you had it configured somewhere else you would need a configuration to show where the cofig file is. Doesn’t make sense, right?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server Management Studio, highlight SQL Server Agent -> Start. Highlight Job ->New Job…, name it , myJob.

1. Under Steps, New Step, name it, Step1,
2. Type: SQL Server Integration Service Package
3. Run as: myProxy
4. Package source: File System
5. Browse to select your package file xxx.dtsx
6. Click Ok

Schedule your job and enable it.........

Comment: i know the steps for sheduling jobs to ssis package. But i want to know how can i specify the .dtsconfig file dynamically during shcedule the job..